# Javascript: Find Other IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, var

I have 5 divs with a class of "ticket-selection" and unique IDs. I figured out how to find each unique ID on click, and add a class. However, I want to find all the other IDs, and remove that class (so only 1 ID has the "active" class). Here's my code:

```
        var $ticket;

        $('.ticket-section').on('click', function(e) {
            $ticket = $(this);
            if (this.id) {
                alert(this.id);
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

I believe I would need to create an array, but I'm not sure how that integrates into this code. Can I say "if this ID is clicked, addClass, but removeClass on the other 4 IDs. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove all `active` class from `.ticket-section` using remove class and add to `this` in the click handler.

```
$('.ticket-section').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active')
```

Comment: @blex `.ticket-section` may not actually be a sibling in HTML.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this. Pretty easy and straight forward. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do this, but this is the simplest, for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.ticket-section').on('click', function(e) {
        $(".active").removeClass("active") ;
        $(this).addClass("active");

    });
```